# How is it better to use two colors in Android?

Tags: android, android-styles

Part of my text in Android Application must be green. Other part - must be black. Code:

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/light_green</item>
```

just change every other TextView to green. How is it better to handle, so I can quickly change light_green to dark_green and standart black color to some other?

**UPD:** Figured out by myself. Solution for those who need it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="text_colorscheme1">@color/black</color>
    <color name="text_colorscheme2">@color/dark_green</color>
    <color name="text_colorscheme2_hint">@color/sea_green</color>

    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="dark_green">#006400</color>
    <color name="light_green">#90EE90</color>
    <color name="sea_green">#2E8B57</color>
 </resources>
```

So I use everywhere text_colorscheme1, text_colorscheme2 and text_colorscheme2_hint.

Comment: Use color resources. Assign them either in layouts or in code.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to set the color you use most often directly in your app theme. If most of the text should be light green, just use

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/light_green</item>
```

To use a different color for a specific TextView just do it as usual. You can style specific Views like EditTexts or Buttons to have different default text colors too, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirement, if you know beforehand that your color is gonna remain same throughout, then it's better that you do it in your `xml` but if it's gonna change at runtime then it's better to use it in code.

Create a file called `color.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <color name="background_color">#888888</color>
        <color name="text_color">#00FFFF</color>
    </resources>
```

Use the resource in your `TextView`

```
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:text="@string/hello" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
    android:textColor="@color/text_color"/>
```

OR

```
text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color));
```